# Upload files (data in excels) in bulk into Oracle SQL Developer using procedure

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wanted to upload files bulk present in my local disk to the server database using procedure.

Is there any way to do that?

I have been searching for a long time and I haven't found anything regarding this, I would be thankfull if someone help me in making this.

Thanks for your time :D

Comment: Hey man check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668734/how-to-copy-the-data-from-excel-to-oracle

Comment: Thanks its working.. !!